# TypeError: $transclude is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There exists solutions for this problem which do not work when implemented into my plunker.

I tried updating the routing library to 1.2.18 and it did not work. Also sometimes an ng-if will throw this error but my code does not contain an ng-if anywhere.

Any help or suggestions would be wonderful.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rrnzNjze2QqkWtjvNUNH?p=preview

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="githubViewer">

      <head>
        <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.1.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.js"></script>
        <script data-require="angular-route@1.2.18" data-semver="1.2.18" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.18/angular-route.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="MainController.js"></script>
        <script src="github.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <h1>Github Viewer</h1>
        <div ng-view=""></div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

MainController.js

```
  var app = angular.module("githubViewer");

  var MainController = function(
    $scope, $interval, $location) {

  var decrementCountdown = function(){
    $scope.countdown -= 1;
    if($scope.countdown < 1){
      $scope.search($scope.username);
    }
  };

  var countdownInterval = null
  var startCountdown = function(){
    countdownInterval = $interval(decrementCountdown, 1000, $scope.countdown);
  };

  $scope.search = function(username){
      if(countdownInterval){
        $interval.cancel(countdownInterval);
        $scope.countdown = null;
      }
      //
  };    

  $scope.username = "angular";
  $scope.countdown = 5;
  startCountdown();
};

  app.controller("MainController", MainController);
```

Comment: I don't see any error related to `$transclude` in console. The only thing which I found is, version mismatch in angular version, changed both pointing to same version solved the issue, [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rrnzNjze2QqkWtjvNUNH?p=preview)

Comment: The console is showing the same error in the plunker you provided that I am receiving in mine. Main.html is not loading into the index like it should. Any ideas why?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/EU1DIJUE2HaU3CTKIxND?p=preview

Comment: That is an improvement thanks! Unfortunately the submit button no loner works though. What did you change?

Comment: 1.2.0rc3 to 1.2.18